# jQuery code assist for FTP projects in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: jquery, aptana3, code-assist

I am looking for a way to add code assist for jQuery in Aptana Studio 3. I know there are plenty of threads here that discuss adding support for **Projects**, but I do all of my development via **FTP**. I don't create Projects in Aptana to work on my sites.

How do I add code assist to Aptana for such work?

If such instructions do exist in SO, my apologies - I didn't see them. Please point me to them.

Comment: Really?!?! No one has any ideas?! C'mon guys! I need help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working on my Mac. I used Transmit for FTP. Since it keeps the files in a cache folder I created my project folder there, so Aptana actually sees the files locally.

The temp folder for Transmit for me was: /Users/plamen/Library/Caches/Cleanup At Startup/Transmit

Although the cache folder might get deleted with my project folder at some point, it's the only solution I have for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get the same here. I'm working over ftp connetcions and code assist is not working witn "projectName->connections->yourconnection" ...

I've tryed a "project->clean" feature as said from the Aptana support... but nothing changed.
Now i'm comparing a std project with a connection prject to figure out if some link missing.
For what i see there is some issue in that case as if uf u create a new std class u have the code assit but u have no info in the docs then. FOr example in php happens this :

$a =  new DOMDocument(); // i have code assis and the list for DOM* classes

$a-> // NO code assists at this point, no attribute list and no method list ... weird

If u hit "ctrl+space" to bring up the code assistant ... u se "No Proposal" that makes me think that aptana does something wrong with documentation pathing in "connection mode" ...

If i get something i'll let you know... please do the same if u find out how to make this work...